# Web console stuck in quasi multiline mode -- bug?

Tags: firefox, multiline, web-console

In the javascript web console, when I press `<enter>` the expression is evaluated, but the input does not clear -- instead a new line is inserted. The behavior is as though I'm pressing both `<enter>` and `<shift>+<enter>` for multi-line input.

I have tried starting firefox in safe-mode, upgrading, and "refreshing" firefox, all to no avail.

Is there some setting that sets multi-line input to the default behavior?

Comment: do you have any extensions for development? say, a javascript beutifier or something? turning them off may do it

Comment: Not that I know of -- wouldn't running firefox in safe mode fix the problem if an extension was the issue? The problem still exists in safe mode.

Comment: I have the same problem, and I’ve tried with a fresh install (version 40) with an entirely new profile.

Comment: Do you by any chance use the Firefox variant called Abrowser? I do, and if you do as well it’s most likely a problem with Abrowser, not Firefox. Need to know which issue tracker to report to :)

Answer (score 0):

I opened the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console), cleared it, and put it next to my Firefox
window. Then I typed an expression in the Web Console and hit enter. The instant
I did so an error appeared in the Browser Console:

```
NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED: Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIPrefBranch.getIntPref] utils.js:555:0
```

That `utils.js:555:0` is a link, taking you to that specific line of that file:

```
WebConsoleUtils._usageCount = Services.prefs.getIntPref("devtools.selfxss.count");
```

Apparently something’s seems to be up with this `devtools.selfxss.count` pref. I
opened [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) to see if I could figure out what.

It turned out that this pref was missing! So I right-clicked, and chose “New >
Integer”, entered `devtools.selfxss.count` as the pref name and `0` as the
value.

It worked!

Then I researched what this pref is all about, and found
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=994134#c89:

> > What does this option exactly do and does setting it to 100 completely
> >     disable this feature or making the message just less likely to appear?
>
> The selfxss prevention works by counting the number of times you have used the
>   console, and turning off paste protection when you cross a certain number,
>   which is at the moment 5 (the number also stops incrementing after that).
>   Alternatively, when you type "allow pasting" into the console when the prompt
>   comes up, this pref is set to a number >5.
>
> Setting it to any number more than 5 should fix this. 100 is just a high
>   enough number that it will be resilient to all change.

The question now is *why* it was missing.

You could check if you’re having the same problem. Otherwise this at least might
be helpful to track down your problem.